# Laravel Fortify and JSON based registering result in CRSF mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm currently toying with Laravel 9.x and Fortify.

For the starter here my environnement :

- Laravel 9.19
- Fortify 1.14
- Postgre 15

I try to achieve something I thought was possible from reading the Fortify doc, using a third-party UI (e.g.: Mobile App) to register and login user.

So, following the documentation guide I deactivated the views generation, and migrated the tables and launched my test server using `php artisan serve`.

Then I try using postman to post the following json to the `/register` route provided by Fortify.

Postman has been setup with the following headers:

- `Content-Type:  application/json`
- `Accept: application/json`

```json
{
  "name": "test1",
  "email": "test1@example.com",
  "password": "MyPassw0rd!",
  "password_confirmation": "MyPassw0rd!"
}
```

The response returned by the request was an `error 419 CSRF Token mismatch`, which I understand since Laravel enforce the use of CSRF token.

Therefor I tried to add the `/register` route to the `except` array inside the middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` and tried again and this time I got a `201 created` response.

From my understanding since the `/register` route exists within the `web` guard hence the CSRF token mechanic.

Since my final goal is to use Fortify with third-party frontend, how can achieve that without putting the route inside the `except` array (if possible)?

Is there a parameter to change inside `config/fortify.php` to allow this behavior?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing I found the solution inside the middleware section of `config/fortify.php`

Replacing

```php
middleware => ['web'],
```

with

```php
middleware => ['api'],
```

Allow to user the register route without having to deactivate the CSRF on the route .